# No response after clicking on Create Gallery button

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Route::group(['middleware' =>'auth'], function(){
Route::prefix('/user/')->group(function(){
Route::get('galleries/create', [GalleryController::class, 'gallerycreate'])->name('galleryCreate');
Route::post('galleries/store', [GalleryController::class, 'gallerystore'])->name('galleryStore');
});

```
        <div class="card-header">Create New Gallery</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action=" {{ route('galleryStore') }}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                
                {{ csrf_field() }}
```

@csrf

```
  <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="description">Gallery Description</label>
                            <textarea name="description" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create Gallery</button>
                    
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: What does your gallerystore action look like?

Comment: thanks for the reply! 

like this:



        Route::post('galleries/store', [GalleryController::class, 'galleryStore'])->name('galleryStore');



public function galleryStore(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [

            'title' => 'required',
            'cover' =>'required' ,
            'description' => 'required'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see it looks like you have included two csrf fields. `{{ csrf_field() }}` and `@csrf` This shouldn't be a big issue but I would expect this to throw an error.

Secondly the GalleryStore action in the GalleryController does not return anything. The action should include something like `return view('some.view')->with(['data' => $data]);`

Comment: thanks! it worked now. and i indented my blade, so the submit button is in the body

Comment: I am glad you got it working. If my answer helped you solve the problem please mark my answer as the correct answer. Have a good day.